# Why won't Firefox grey out my disabled select options?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have this Javascript:

```
let projectBox = document.getElementById("invoice_project_id");
let taskBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("tasks");

function filterTasks() {
    let project = projectBox.options[projectBox.selectedIndex];
    let results = Array.from(taskOptions).filter(task => {
        return task.getAttribute("data-project-id") == project.value || task.value == "";
    })
    Array.from(taskBoxes).forEach(taskBox => {
        let source = taskBox.closest(".source");
        if (results.length > 2) {
            source.classList.add("active");
            taskBox.innerHTML = "";
            results.forEach(result => {
                if (result.getAttribute("data-charged") == "true") {
                    result.disabled = true; // some options get disabled here which works perfectly in all browsers except Firefox
                }
                taskBox.add(result.cloneNode(true));
            })
        } else {
            source.classList.remove("active");
        }
    })
}
```

It works perfectly in all browser, except Firefox (the latest version on a Mac).

For some reason, in Firefox, the disabled select options are *not* (!) greyed out. They are disabled in the HTML but they look like all the other, enabled options.

What am I missing here?

Is this a Firefox bug or is there something wrong with my code?

**HTML:**

```
<select class="tasks">
  <option value="">Please select a task...</option>
  <option data-project-id="375" data-charged="false" value="413">Do something</option>
  <option data-project-id="375" data-charged="true" value="196" disabled="">Do something else</option>
  <option data-project-id="375" data-charged="true" value="199" disabled="">Yet another task</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is not standard browser default styling defined in the spec as far as I know; if you need the consistency, you'll have to provide the styles to enforce this.

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* For one thing, you're missing your HTML in your [mcve] to show what exactly you're working with...

Comment: Firefox on Windows does gray out disabled `<option>` tags, so it seems likely your issue is related to the additional things you are doing and/or possibly a Mac Firefox bug. But without an example to allow us to reproduce the problem it's hard to tell more than that.

Comment: Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmtezb9w/). In my PC (Windows 10) the default style-sheet just adds a barely noticeable gray font color but the look is definitively different and you can also add custom CSS. As already said, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Herohtar: OK, I just added my HTML above. It's fairly standard, though. When I change `disabled=""` to `disabled="true"` in the console that doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Yes, your fiddle looks exactly as it should in my installation of Firefox for Mac. The disabled option has red text and a pink background. I guess there must be something wrong with my Javascript then.

Comment: If you are applying any styles, that could also be overriding some of the default behavior. It would be useful to see what CSS is being used as well.

Comment: Solution found! Thanks, @Herohtar! In my CSS I had `&:-moz-focusring { color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000000; }`, a hack to remove dotted outlines from select elements in Firefox. So apparently, using that hack also impacts on the appearance of the contained `option` elements. Weird!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my CSS I had a Firefox-specific hack to remove dotted outlines from select elements:

```
&:-moz-focusring { // remove dotted outline in Firefox
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000000;
}
```

Removing this from my CSS fixed the disabled options and made them look normal again.

The dotted outlines are now visible again but I no longer care so much. It's just a matter of taste I guess...

Comment: It's mostly a matter of accessibility ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this today and found that for some reason Firefox no longer respects the `opacity` setting for options.  I previously had this rule which was working on Firefox:

```
option:disabled { opacity: 0.4; }
```

Furthermore, setting a `color` attribute on the parent `select` seems to break the native style for disabled options.  Workaround was to change my `opacity` rule to `color`:

```
option:disabled { color: #ccc; }
```

This gives more or less the same visual.  It's a bit odd that setting `color` on a select menu would break browser support for disabled options - might go so far as to say this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me (only Firefox). Note: Important change color, if use #000 dont work to remove gray background into the options:

```css
select{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
option{
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #222;
}
```